# How to filter Products with activated Flag?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, rules

I use the `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` flag. How can I filter only products having this flag set to yes? Is there a table where it is set so that I can use it for filtering?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Solution myself. Just wanna share it with you :)

There is a Table called `catalog_eav_attribute` which shows us in some row if the product is used for promo rules.

So what I've done is. I injected the Attribute Collection from `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection`

and set up my DI in my Model like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection $attributeCollection
)
{
    $this->_attributeCollection = $attributeCollection;
}
```

and now i can loop over the collection like this:

```
$collection = $this->_attributeCollection->addFieldToFilter('is_used_for_promo_rules', 1)->load();

foreach ($collection as $test) {
     $id = $test->getId();
     $name = $test->getName();
}
```

now the `$name` will be your Attribute Code and `$id` the Attribute Id